How to generate all dates in a range when grouping by date in Entity Framework Core?
I'm working with Entity Framework Core and I'm trying to group orders by date within a specific date range. The goal is to get the count of orders for each day in the range, including days with zero orders.
Here is my code:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

await using OrdersContext db = new OrdersContext();

var from = new DateTime(2023, 12, 28).ToUniversalTime();
var to = from.AddDays(30);
var group = await db.Orders
    .Where(x => x.OrderDate >= from && x.OrderDate <= to)
    .GroupBy(x => x.OrderDate.Date)
    .Select(x => new { Day = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Day)
    .ToListAsync();
group.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Day}: {x.Count}"));

public class OrdersContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(
            "Host=localhost;Database=ef_core_missing_days;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"
        );
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Order>()
            .HasData(
                new Order { Id = 1, OrderDate = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1).ToUniversalTime() },
                new Order { Id = 2, OrderDate = new DateTime(2024, 1, 2).ToUniversalTime() },
                new Order { Id = 3, OrderDate = new DateTime(2024, 1, 3).ToUniversalTime() },
                new Order { Id = 4, OrderDate = new DateTime(2024, 1, 5).ToUniversalTime() },
                new Order { Id = 5, OrderDate = new DateTime(2024, 1, 7).ToUniversalTime() }
            );
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}

The problem is that the output only prints the days that have orders in the database:
2024-01-01: 1
2024-01-02: 1
2024-01-03: 1
2024-01-05: 1
2024-01-07: 1

However, I want to generate all days within the range (from 2023-12-28 to 2024-01-27) and show a count of 0 for the days that do not have any orders.
How can I modify my query to include all dates in the range, even those without any orders?
I’ve tried manually adding the missing days in the result set after querying, but this is not what I need. I’m looking for a solution that works directly with IQueryable, without manually manipulating the data after it’s retrieved.

The easiest way to do this is just to fill missing days in C# and add it to group collection:
for (var i = from; i <= to; i = i.AddDays(1))
{
    if (!group.Any(x => x.Day == i))
        group.Add(new { Day = i, Count = 0 });
}

// And orderagain after end:
groups = groups.OrderBy(x => x.Day).ToList();


I don't think it is possilebe because IQueryable represents a query expression that is translated to SQL by EF Core. You could try turn the IQueryable to .AsEnumerable(), then you could use append method for implicit type of object.
            var group = db.Orders
                .Where(x => x.OrderDate >= from && x.OrderDate <= to)
                .GroupBy(x => x.OrderDate.Date)
                .Select(x => new { Day = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                .AsEnumerable();

            for (DateTime day = from; day <= to; day = day.AddDays(1))
            {                             
                if (!group.Any(x => x.Day == day))
                {
                    group=group.Append(new  { Day = day, Count = 0 });
                }                
            }

            var final = group.OrderBy(x => x.Day).ToList();
           
            final.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Day}: {x.Count}"));


if you have the list ready with the date range with order counts, then you have to simply group by month and sort by month according to your requirement like ascending or descending.
var monthlyWiseCounts = dailyCounts
        .GroupBy(dc => new { dc.Date.Year, dc.Date.Month })
        .Select(g => new MonthlyOrderCount
        {
            Year = g.Key.Year,
            Month = g.Key.Month,
            TotalOrders = g.Sum(dc => dc.Count)
        })
        .OrderByDescending(mc => mc.Year)
        .ThenByDescending(mc => mc.Month)
        .ToList();

    return monthlyWiseCounts;

